# mysql search by year from date string

Tags: mysql

I have a large database with over 3 million records. I want to search the by date but the date field is stored as a sting in this format 2014-01-20 00:00

I am looking to search the database in the quickest possible way.

I am looking for something LIKE :

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Date > 2012 AND Date < 2014
```

Any pointers as I dont know where to start

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the left statement

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE left(Date,4) > 2012 AND left(Date,4) < 2014
```

Comment: perfect solution , I accepted this one as it is the simplest and I had never heard of the left function before, taouhgt me alot, thanks phincon

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function for this. In your case, the format string would be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i`. So this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) BETWEEN 2012 AND 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the extract function. Here is an example :

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Name
WHERE extract(year from date_column) BETWEEN 2012 AND 2014
```

You can do this with months, days, and even up to seconds.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_extract.asp